# inserting data using servlets in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class app1conn {
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",uname,password;
Connection con;
PreparedStatement ps;

app1conn() throws SQLException{

   DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
   con= DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");

}

public void insert (String name,String email,String age,String dob)throws Exception{


     ps=con.prepareStatement(url);
    //ps=new con.PreparedStatement ("insert into info(name,email,age,dob) values(?,?,?,?)") ;
    ps.setString(1,name);
    ps.setString(2,email);
    ps.setString(3,age);
    ps.setString(4,dob);
    ps.executeUpdate();

    }
public Vector getData() throws SQLException{
    ps=con.prepareStatement("Select * from info");
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
    ResultSetMetaData rms=rs.getMetaData();
    Vector data=new Vector();

    while(rs.next()){

        Vector temp=new Vector();
        temp.add(rs.getString(1));
        temp.add(rs.getString(2));
        temp.add(rs.getString(3));
        temp.add(rs.getString(4));
        temp.add(rs.getString(5));


        data.add(temp);

    }
    return data;
}

 public Vector getDataById(String id) throws SQLException{
    ps=con.prepareStatement("Select * from info where id=?");
    ps.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(id));
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
    ResultSetMetaData rms=rs.getMetaData();
    Vector data=new Vector();

    while(rs.next()){

        Vector temp=new Vector();
        temp.add(rs.getString(1));
        temp.add(rs.getString(2));
        temp.add(rs.getString(3));
        temp.add(rs.getString(4));
        temp.add(rs.getString(5));


        data.add(temp);

    }
    return data;
 }
    void update_info(String name,String email,String age,String dob,String id) throws SQLException{
        ps=con.prepareStatement ("update info set name=?,email=?,age=?,dob=? where id=?");
        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, email);
        ps.setString(3, age);
        ps.setString(4, dob);


        ps.executeUpdate();
    }

}
```

i am trying to insert the data..
when i click on submit button..

it shows null as an output..

Comment: This doesn't look much like Javascript..

Comment: why is tagged as javascript?

Comment: Where are the servlets? There is none in the code you provide...

Comment: how to compile something like "String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",uname,password;"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String insertSQL = "insert into info(name,email,age,dob) values(?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
    ps.setString(1,name);
    ps.setString(2,email);
    ps.setString(3,age);
    ps.setString(4,dob);
    ps.executeUpdate();
```

Or

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
        + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
        + "(?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 11);
preparedStatement.setString(2, "abc");
preparedStatement.setString(3, "system");
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());
// execute insert SQL stetement
preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
```

Refer to [this article](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/)

Comment: Refer to the article link I have provided, it's work. I have tried that one so many times.

Answer (score 0):

Have you trace your code on which line you got null value???

Try this code instead of yours.

```
public boolean insert (String name,String email,String age,String dob){
 PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
 try{
 preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("insert into info(name, email, age, dob) values(?,?,?,?)");
 preparedStatement.setString(1,name);
 preparedStatement.setString(2,email);
 preparedStatement.setString(3,age);
 preparedStatement.setString(4,dob);
 preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
 }
   return true;
}
```